# Ruby Selenium Net::ReadTimeout

Tags: ruby, selenium, jenkins, cucumber, capybara

I'm running automated tests using Ruby/Cucumber/Capybara/Chromedriver. The automated tests are running by jenkins. Strange thing is that sometimes the browser opens up, but with a black screen and i got Net::ReadTimeout, and the browser not closing, so taking up my Memory. What i would like to achieve is, that if this occurs the browser with black screen must be closed. Any suggestions?
Here's the error i got in jenkins:

```
    Net::ReadTimeout (Net::ReadTimeout)
/var/lib/jenkins/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/net/protocol.rb:176:in `rbuf_fill'
/var/lib/jenkins/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/net/protocol.rb:154:in `readuntil'
/var/lib/jenkins/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/net/protocol.rb:164:in `readline'
/var/lib/jenkins/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/net/http/response.rb:40:in `read_status_line'
/var/lib/jenkins/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/net/http/response.rb:29:in `read_new'
/var/lib/jenkins/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/net/http.rb:1446:in `block in transport_request'
/var/lib/jenkins/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/net/http.rb:1443:in `catch'
/var/lib/jenkins/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/net/http.rb:1443:in `transport_request'
/var/lib/jenkins/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/net/http.rb:1416:in `request'
/var/lib/jenkins/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/net/http.rb:1409:in `block in request'
/var/lib/jenkins/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/net/http.rb:877:in `start'
/var/lib/jenkins/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/net/http.rb:1407:in `request'
/var/lib/jenkins/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.0.5/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:124:in `response_for'
/var/lib/jenkins/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.0.5/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:78:in `request'
/var/lib/jenkins/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.0.5/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:63:in `call'
/var/lib/jenkins/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.0.5/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:645:in `raw_execute'
/var/lib/jenkins/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.0.5/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:109:in `create_session'
/var/lib/jenkins/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.0.5/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:69:in `initialize'
/var/lib/jenkins/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.0.5/lib/selenium/webdriver/chrome/bridge.rb:42:in `initialize'
/var/lib/jenkins/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.0.5/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:61:in `new'
/var/lib/jenkins/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.0.5/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:61:in `for'
/var/lib/jenkins/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.0.5/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:82:in `for'
/var/lib/jenkins/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/capybara-2.11.0/lib/capybara/selenium/driver.rb:22:in `browser'
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/autotest/features/support/env.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/jenkins/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/cucumber-2.4.0/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:96:in `load'
/var/lib/jenkins/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/cucumber-2.4.0/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:96:in `load_code_file'
/var/lib/jenkins/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/cucumber-2.4.0/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:142:in `load_file'
/var/lib/jenkins/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/cucumber-2.4.0/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:84:in `block in load_files!'
/var/lib/jenkins/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/cucumber-2.4.0/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:83:in `each'
/var/lib/jenkins/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/cucumber-2.4.0/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:83:in `load_files!'
/var/lib/jenkins/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/cucumber-2.4.0/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:253:in `load_step_definitions'
/var/lib/jenkins/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/cucumber-2.4.0/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:61:in `run!'
/var/lib/jenkins/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/cucumber-2.4.0/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:32:in `execute!'
/var/lib/jenkins/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/cucumber-2.4.0/bin/cucumber:8:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/jenkins/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/bin/cucumber:22:in `load'
/var/lib/jenkins/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/bin/cucumber:22:in `<main>'
```

Comment: make sure to start the selenium session only when the application is properly started.

Comment: We are running into this same issue. On ubuntu 14.04 with all the dependencies installed and chrome can be started up in a terminal via xvfb. But when I start it up via ruby (selenium in our case) it just times out with the same stack trace in this question. So far have not found a solution

Answer (score 0):

Trace where, exactly, this error is coming from in your code, then

```
begin
    <driver execution code>
rescue Net::ReadTimeout
    @driver.quit
end
```

This should catch the error and close the session as you desire.

What I've done, is write a separate method to handle errors

```
def rescue_exceptions
    begin
        yield
    rescue Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError,
            Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError,
            Selenium::WebDriver::Error::StaleElementReferenceError,
            Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotInteractableError
        <Handle Errors Here>
    end
end
```

Then this method can be wrapped around other code that may cause issues

```
def SignIn
    rescue_exceptions {
        <Perform Actions Here>
    }
end
```